# Pgfplots: shading with different colours

Tags: pgfplots

I have this picture:

[image]

It was generated using this code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.14, label style={font=\huge}, tick label style={font=\huge}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=-4:4, samples=100,
  axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=5cm, width=16cm,
  xtick={-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  xticklabels={-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, %  so do it manually instead
  ]

  \addplot [very thick,black, name path=f] {gauss(0,1)};



    \path[name path=axis](axis cs:-2,0) -- (axis cs:-1,0);
    \addplot[thick, color=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and axis, soft clip={domain=-2:-1},];

       \path[name path=axis](axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
    \addplot[thick, color=blue, fill=blue, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and axis, soft clip={domain=1:2},];

         \path[name path=axis](axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-2,0);
    \addplot[thick, color=yellow, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and axis, soft clip={domain=-3:-2},];

        \path[name path=axis](axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:3,0);
    \addplot[thick, color=yellow, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and axis, soft clip={domain=2:3},];

        \path[name path=axis](axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);
    \addplot[thick, color=red, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5] fill between [of=f and axis, soft clip={domain=-1:1},];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to get rid of that white triangle. That is, the area from -1 to 1 should all be red.

How can I get this?

As a backup, if that doesn't work, doing red in (-1, 1) and doing red overlapping with blue in (-2, 2) and red and blue overlapping with yellow in (-3, 3) would also work (might even be better...)

Comment: On my updated TeXLive 2019 installation, I do get a full red region. When was the last time you updated your TeX installation? BTW, if you use `\path[name path=axis](axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:3,0);`, you do not need to add all the other `\path[name path=axis]...;` commands since you use `soft clip` anyway.

Comment: I checked for updates and it says TeXShop is up to date (version 4.44).

Comment: I am not sure but I thought TeXShop was an editor, not a TeX installation. Be it as it may, at least I cannot reproduce your issue, and thus not fix it. (But did you try using one `\path[name path=axis]...;` command instead of several?)

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat, I tried, but just one `\path[...]` did not help. I guess it must be the installation. Weird, as it hasn't done this with any of my other similar figures.